# Traer siguiente hora en una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una vista en donde se hace seguimiento a un grupo de asesores, con un IINER JOIN traigo el estado y otra información relevante, con la siguiente estructura:

`ALTER VIEW PVE.TIEMPOSPARADA
(ID VARCHAR(255)
    , Estado VARCHAR(255)
    , HORA TIME
    , FECHA DATE)`

Algunos datos de prueba:

```
ID | ESTADO | HORA | FECHA
123 | Disponible | 7:00 | 21-04-2020
123 | Break | 10:00 | 21-04-2020
123 | Disponible | 10:30 | 21-04-2020
123 | Almuerzo | 13:00 | 21-04-2020
1234 | Disponible | 7:10 | 21-04-2020
1234 | Break | 10:05 | 21-04-2020
1234 | Disponible | 10:30 | 21-04-2020
1234 | Almuerzo | 13:15 | 21-04-2020
123 | Disponible | 7:00 | 22-04-2020
123 | Break | 10:00 | 22-04-2020
123 | Disponible | 10:30 | 22-04-2020
123 | Almuerzo | 13:00 | 22-04-2020
1234 | Disponible | 7:10 | 22-04-2020
1234 | Break | 10:05 | 22-04-2020
1234 | Disponible | 10:30 | 22-04-2020
1234 | Almuerzo | 13:15 | 22-04-2020
```

Mi pregunta es, como hago para traer la hora siguiente por fecha y por asesor para calcular el tiempo que estuvo en X estado

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de funciones de ventana, con la cláusula **OVER** que determina las particiones **(PARTITION BY)** y el orden de un conjunto de filas.

```
SELECT ID, ESTADO, FECHA, HORA 
, LEAD(HORA) OVER(PARTITION BY FECHA, ID ORDER BY HORA) HORA_FIN
FROM ASESORES
```

En este caso lo particionas por la fecha y el Id de Usuario y le puedes dar un ordenamiento por Hora (GROUP BY). Una vez particionado, para traer la hora siguiente, es decir de la fila posterior, haces uso de la función **LEAD**.